# What's the difference between word vectors, word representations and vector embeddings?

Tags: terminology

I have seen word vectors, word representations and vector embedding in those papers (and in a few other places):

- https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~amnih/papers/wordreps.pdf : words embeddings
- http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3781 : word representations
- http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/papers/wvSent_acl2011.pdf: word vectors

What's the difference between word vectors, word representations and vector embeddings?

I would say that a word vector is a kind of word representation, but how about vector embeddings?

Comment: Before going to the trouble of (trying to) read all three papers, I will say that there are a lot of [meanings in use for _word_,](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/threekindsofword.pdf) especially in differing fields, like linguistics and AI. Hence, what one person means by _word vector_ may be quite different from what somebody else understands by it.

Answer (score 3):

- Word vectors are the same as word embeddings. (2)
- A word representation is a mathematical object associated with each word, often a vector (1). Word vectors/embeddings are one type of word representations, amongst others. Word vectors are one the most common types of word representation in the current NLP literature nowadays.

---

(1): Turian, Joseph, Lev Ratinov, and Yoshua Bengio. "[Word representations: a simple and general method for semi-supervised learning](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=7872411552705927180&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5)." Proceedings of the 48th annual meeting of the association for computational linguistics. Association for Computational Linguistics, 2010.

(2): https://youtu.be/MRH9ABxCUZ0?t=28m30s